# Android CWAC-Camera rotation issues after upgrading to 0.6.3

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am using the CWAC-Camera library within my Android application. Recently it was upgraded to v0.6.3, but since then I have noticed that rotation of images doesn't seem to work as expected.

I am starting a `CameraFragment` within an Activity that is locked to landscape orientation, and have observed the rotation is not correct for an output image with or without setting `CameraFragment.lockToLandscape(true)`. I have managed to reproduce this in the demo application when the "Lock to Landscape" is checked (steps and a screenshot provided below). I have been testing on a Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 both running Android 4.4.2.

Has anyone else experienced this issue since upgrading to v0.6? Previously we were using 0.5.4 which didn't seem to have this issue, but looking at the release log I see there has been a lot of changes to EXIF data/rotation etc.

Steps to reproduce in demo app:

1. Open application, hold phone portrait or landscape
2. Select "Lock to Landscape" and "Single shot mode" from menu
3. Turn phone landscape (if started off portrait in step 1)
4. Capture image, appears rotated as per screenshot.

[image: screenshot of demo application]

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide precise steps to reproduce this using the Nexus 4 or Nexus 5 using the demo app? For example, I just took a picture with the demo app, using the rear-facing camera, on a Nexus 5, using the demo app. The photo saved to external storage is properly oriented.

Comment: Note that the aforementioned test was in landscape mode. I also tried the same test (landscape, rear-facing, Nexus 5, demo app), in single-shot mode, to get to the activity that you have screenshotted above. Once again, the image is fine.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I've added the steps that I am going through above. I may not have been clear enough before, but it looks like setting "Lock to Landscape" true is the most important step for this issue, as I don't have the issue when this isn't set on the Nexus 5 or 4.

Comment: Sorry, should have also mentioned that I opened an issue on Github [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/138)

Comment: I thought this sounded familiar... I will be looking at your issue later this week, when I should have some time to do some work on the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this bug was fixed in v0.6.4 of the library.

Comment: I am getting the same issue with my Nexus 5... The first picture taken is correctly oriented however, the next ones are not... Then, if the fragment is initialised again it happens all over again: first picture correct, others wrong. On the nexus 4, this isn't happening - all the photos are correct. Any help?

Comment: @Daniel: If you can reproduce the problem using the demo app, file an issue and provide me exact steps for reproducing it. If you can reproduce it with your own code and can publish that code somewhere (e.g., GitHub), file an issue and provide me with exact steps for reproducing the problem using your code.